# The third covariant of a tensor in Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I'm reading Petersen's book "Riemannian Geometry 3rd", No.171 in GTM. On page 82, there's a formula reads:

$$\nabla^3_{X,Y,Z}W=\nabla^2_{X,Y}(\nabla_ZW)-\nabla_{\nabla^2_{XY}Z}W$$

I'm quite puzzled with this formula. On the right hand site, it doesn't seem to be tensorial in the "Z" position. Is this formula false?

Comment: Doesn't look hopeless to me. You should check $C^{\infty}$ linearity explicitly; it looks highly likely that the ugly terms you get by expanding this whole thing would cancel each other out because if you multiply $Z$ by a function $f$ you'll have double covariant derivative acting on $f$ on both terms (one is positive, the other is negative); hence it's very likely they cancel out. My suggestion is that you do the calculation explicitly and see where you get.

Comment: Have you tried checking the tensoriality of the corresponding formula for the second covariant tensor of a connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah I don't think that formula works as written; there are some missing terms.

The good news is that the omitted terms don't matter in context. The purpose of the formula in the context of the book was to compute the difference $\nabla^3_{X,Y,Z} W - \nabla^3_{Y,X,Z} W$. The omitted terms are symmetric in $X$ and $Y$, so they cancel out.

---

The rest of this answer is just the details. My claim is that:
$$
  \nabla^2_{X,Y}(\nabla_Z W)
  = \nabla^3_{X,Y,Z} W
    + \nabla_{\nabla^2_{X,Y} Z} W
    + \nabla^2_{X,\nabla_Y Z} W
    + \nabla^2_{Y,\nabla_X Z} W
$$
Note the last two terms, which didn't appear in the original formula.

I'll do the computation in index notation, but I'm sure you can do it at home in whatever notation you prefer. We can translate $\nabla^2_{X,Y}(\nabla_Z W)$ to index notation and expand using the product rule twice:
\begin{align}
  & X^i Y^j \nabla_i \nabla_j (Z^k \nabla_k W^\ell) \\
  &= X^i Y^j \nabla_i (
    \nabla_j Z^k \nabla_k W^\ell
    + Z^k \nabla_j \nabla_k W^\ell
    ) \\
  &= X^i Y^j (
    \nabla_i \nabla_j Z^k \nabla_k W^\ell
    + \nabla_j Z^k \nabla_i \nabla_k W^\ell
    + \nabla_i Z^k \nabla_j \nabla_k W^\ell  
    + Z^k \nabla_i \nabla_j \nabla_k W^\ell
    )
  \end{align}
In this, the first term is $\nabla_{\nabla^2_{X,Y} Z} W$, the second term is $\nabla^2_{X,\nabla_Y Z} W$, the third term is $\nabla^2_{Y,\nabla_X Z} W$, and the last term is $\nabla^3_{X,Y,Z} W$.